# php with mysql, the code is not inserting into my table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, procedure

Big edit:

New script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);
$nazwabazydanych = "projekt";

$pesel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pesel']);
$imie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imie']);  
$nazwisko = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nazwisko']);
$telefon = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefon']);
$adres = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adres']);
$nr_konta = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nr_konta']);
$zarobek = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zarobek']);

if (!$pesel || !$imie || !$nazwisko || !$telefon || !$adres || !$nr_konta || !$zarobek)

 {
        print "Nie zostały wypełnione wszystkie pola";
        exit;
 }


$db = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$db)  
        {  
        print "Nie można nawiązać połączenia z bazą danych";
        exit;
        }

mysql_select_db("$nazwabazydanych");

$query = mysql_query("CALL dodaj_osobe ('$pesel','$imie','$nazwisko','$telefon','$adres','$nr_konta','$zarobek')"); 

?>
```

Action:

```
<form action="lool.php" method="post">

PESEL: <input type="text" name="pesel" maxlength=11 size=12><br><br> 
Imię: <input type="text" name="imie" maxlength=45 size=46><br><br>
Nazwisko: <input type="text" name="nazwisko" maxlength=45 size=46><br><br>
Telefon: <input type="text" name="telefon" maxlength=9 size=10><br><br>
Adres: <input type="text" name="adres" maxlength=45 size=46><br><br>
Numer konta: <input type="text" name="nr_konta" maxlength=20 size=21><br><br>
Zarobek: <input type="text" name="zarobek" maxlength=8 size=9><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Dodaj klienta">
</form>
```

And the updated error:

NONE!

Thanks guys, but I got a question:
How can I send an error if for example "nr_konta" or "pesel" or "telefon" are too low digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually getting the $_POST values.

Should be

```
$pesel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pesel']);
$imie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imie']);  
$nazwisko = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nazwisko']);
$telefon = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefon']);
$adres = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adres']);
$nr_konta = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nr_konta']);
$zarobek = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zarobek']);
```

And those should go before your

`if (!$pesel || !$imie || !$nazwisko || !$telefon || !$adres || !$nr_konta || !$zarobek)`

Also, you need to remove the `$` from your `$_POST` values.

`$_POST['$imie']`

Should be:

`$_POST['imie']`

Comment: It's because you have `$_POST['$imie']`. It should be `$_POST['imie']` This: `$imie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['$imie']);` should be `$imie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imie']);`

Comment: Grab my code block and replace it with yours. You should't have the `$` in `$_POST['$imie']` just `$_POST['imie']`

Comment: Did you update your code? Replace your block of code with my first block of code. What's the error?

Comment: You did it mate, my small mistake! :) 
Can you although answear my next question? How can I send an error if the digts count is too low?

Comment: What digts count? Is that one of the columns? And if so, which one?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get POST variables using the $_POST array, unless you have `register_globals` on.

```
$pesel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pesel']);
$imie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imie']);  
$nazwisko = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nazwisko']);
$telefon = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefon']);
$adres = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adres']);
$nr_konta = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nr_konta']);
$zarobek = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zarobek']);

// Put this after so you don't have to restate the $_POST vars
if (!$pesel || !$imie || !$nazwisko || !$telefon || !$adres || !$nr_konta || !$zarobek)

 {
        print "Nie zostały wypełnione wszystkie pola";
        exit;
 }
```

Comment: You need to move the `if (!$pesel || !$imie || !$nazwisko || !$telefon || !$adres || !$nr_konta || !$zarobek)

 {
        print "Nie zostały wypełnione wszystkie pola";
        exit;
 }` code to below

Answer (score 2):

Use  `print_r($_POST)` you should see if you get values. In your code the problem seems to be that you are not using the correct indexes. Note Pesel doesn't have a notice but imie does.

Your code for the two:

```
$pesel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pesel']);
$imie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['$imie']);
```

Note you have `'$imie'` as the index. I'm guessing copy and paste error here. From the html it seems the element is named imie.
Try this:

```
$imie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imie']);
```

Comment: Changed it this way, but I am getting new error after this change.